# Magento 2 Check if error then redirect to custom url

Tags: redirect, plugins, magento2

I am using createPost plugin. But issue with this is, I want to redirect it to custom url if error occured in createPost() default execute function.

For example, if customer with same email id already exist then it goes in catch of default createPost() execute function's catch. I wants to redirect it to my custom page.

Please note, No code to add in try. So try catch is not used.

Also tried with throw exception but I don't know how to redirect with throw exception or with throw it is possible or not.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory:

$resultRedirect = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_REDIRECT);

return $resultRedirect->setPath('custom/page/index');

Try this in your catch block to redirect.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Thanks for answering but can you also add an explanation on how your code solves the issue? Also check the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for info on how to format code.

Comment: @karthikeyan, Yes it is used for redirection but I want to perform action when default file return error without putting try catch in my plugin file.